# How i can login into basecamp using our site.

Tags: authentication, oauth, basecamp

I want to login using mysite in basecamp. Mean when i open login page after enter user name & password i will redirect to basecamp dashboard & i will see all my project list as usual on basecamp.

Comment: you can check Basecamp API details from their github repo:
https://github.com/basecamp/api

Comment: thanks its working fine